# QML application launcher similar to iOS

Tags: qml

I'm trying to write an application launcher using QtQuick\QML, and I'd like the user experience to be similar to iOS, in terms of having a grid of icons that can be rearranged with icons that "move out of the way" via animated transitions and a "snap to grid" effect if the icon is dropped in an intermediate position.  I've tried using GridView and the drag properties, but I can't seem to get the layout do what I want.  What would be the best way to implement this type of app using QML? I'm fairly new to QtQuick, and I feel like maybe I'm missing something fundamental that would make this fairly easy\obvious to write.

Comment: Can you be more explicit in what you already tried? Maybe show some code?

Answer (score 0):

For putting icons in a grid, you can use the grid view:
http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qml-gridview.html

Go through the Qt Quick documentation, you will find out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly relevant to implementing the grid of icons, but I recently came across the QML component Loader. This lets you load QML components on demand, and could be useful for the code that launches an app after the icon is selected.

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qml-qtquick2-loader.html

Answer (score 0):

I have made Nokia N9 launched look and feel (Maemo 6, or also known as MeeGo).
It is similar, I just scroll from up to down with icons, while you change "pages" from left to right (and vice versa).

I don't know is it best way, but this is how I did icon manager (its shrinked, **this is only to give you idea - in reality it is considerably larger**):

```
Item
{
    id: root

    function getChildAt(x, y) {}
    function getIndexOfChild(child) {}
    function moveChild(child, x, y)
    {
        //moving around icons
    }

    function setIndexToChild(child)
    {
        //index of child in Grid element (where to drop)
    }

    Flickable
    {
        id: scroller
        clip: true
        //you most likely want HorizontalFlick ("paging" effect you can add on onBeginingXChanged)
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick

        contentHeight: iconTable.height
        contentWidth: iconTable.width

        Grid
        {
            id: iconTable

            width: root.width
            anchors.top: parent.top
            flow: Grid.LeftToRight
            spacing: 10

            add: Transition
            {
                NumberAnimation
                {
                    properties: "x,y"
                    //make desired transition
                }
            }
            move: Transition
            {
                NumberAnimation
                {
                    properties: "x,y"
                    //make desired transition
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also write down your own implementation of manager in C++ and later on use it in QML.

---

This is how it looks like:

[image: Preview of icon manager]

Answer (score 0):

I created something distantly connected to this recently, the idea is: create a ListView with snapping. Its delegate should contain a GridView. Separate all of the apps into n-element chunks. Then (it's only the idea)

```
ListModel
{
    ListElement { apps: [app1, app2, ..., appn] }
    ListElement { apps: [app1, app2, ..., appn] }
    ....
    ListElement { apps: [app1, app2, ..., appk] }
}
```

Then populate the ListView with this model and the GridView with the `apps` property.
I don't know whether you can provide drag and drop here, though